# How to config Client side capabilities with json

Tags: java, json, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I set up a java/testng script, I create client-side required capabilites or options for the RemoteWebdriver and/or FirefoxOptions/ChromeOptions etc. via various setters. However when we setup the hub or node we can pass in json configuration files.

Is there a way to configure client-side Capabilites  via a json Object/file? The documentation seems to suggest there is:

According to the Selenium documentation [DesiredCapabilities](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:wP65tk0Kh4oJ:https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)

> ... Therefore, the client and server should use JSON objects with the properties listed below when describing which features a user requests that a session support.

I don't see anything in the RemoteWebDriver class to handle this. Does someone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: If this is not possible it would make for a great enhancement